# Can not find C# Chat room

Tags: support, questions

I can not find chat room for c sharp, can anyone let me know that where it is ?

Comment: is it possible that a: you were on the wrong chat server (chat.MSO or chat.SE perhaps, instead of chat.SO), or b: you had the "favorites" tab active in the room index (which filters the list to rooms you have marked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask, [we serve](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c)

[image]

Comment: why I could not find it ? How can you find it ?

Comment: I couldnt search for it either ... when you type c# in the search box and hit enter, nothing happens at all.