# Why so many chats?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, chat

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69896/can-not-find-c-chat-room) made me wonder why each site has its own chat. Since chat features multiple rooms, it already handles multiple topics and sub-communities.

The problem with multiple chat sites is that you might not be able to find what you're looking for, or you might be unsure which room in which site is most appropriate. You also risk fracturing the community (to a far greater extent than you do simply with SE sites, since each chat can have lots of rooms).

So what are the benefits of per-site chat? Is it best that it stay this way, or do you think it should change?

---

Edit: shame on me for not noticing that SE sites are lumped together and SOFU sites are not. Same question, though: why not justonechat.thewholedamnsite.com?

Comment: Isn't all chats on chat.stackexchange.com now? (except the original trilogy)

Comment: @Downvoter Aye, that is the case now.

Comment: @Grace @Down - true. Same question, though. Why so many chats?

Comment: Why so serious?

Comment: Hello, Mr. Serious. May I call you so? Oh, that didn't quite work, did it...

Comment: Re. your edit: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69023/why-do-only-non-generically-named-domain-sites-get-full-chat-sites

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update:

We are throwing the floor open re [chat.SU](http://chat.superuser.com/rooms/38/thoughts-on-merging) and [chat.SF](http://chat.serverfault.com/rooms/42/thoughts-on-merging). Add your thoughts now!

---

There aren't *many* - most are on [chat.SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/), where (as you say) we get the advantages of a single hub, allowing parallel/separate discussions, but also cross-site discussion (so there's always someone to talk to).

However, SO is always the gorilla; the usage there is an order of magnitude higher - and I suspect that if we put SO into chat.SE it would cause a bit more confusion.

SU and SF are different again. By *usage* maybe they could go into SE, but they weren't really *born* through SE. The are SOFU, not SE. Of course, by *their most similar discipline* maybe we could have SU/SF/SO on one hub.

And MSO? hmm... well... er... hmmm... MSO is a curious beast; in part it discusses stackoverflow.com and in part it discusses the Stack Exchange Network. *Maybe* chat.MSO should be shared among chat.SE and chat.SO.

At the moment we're pretty content with the split, but it is something we discuss regularly internally.

Comment: I would definitely recommend moving chat.meta into SE, and probably SF and SU, too. SO certainly is a gorilla.

Comment: @JonB see edit for more

Comment: @JonB [Not really.](https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=tbsAp-FUY59HF83vJN_a1qg)

Comment: @radp - is that since inception? Because meta chat opened WAY before the others. You might look at avg/day instead.

Comment: @JonB it's all non-deleted messages ever. I don't have enough data to get you averages, unfortunately.