# Put all Stack Exchange chatrooms together?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

This has been bothering me for a while now. When you are in a chat-room for example in Stack Overflow, you are also able to be in, at the same time, as many other rooms in the Stack Overflow chat.

The same goes for Meta Stack Overflow, Super User, etcetera.

The problem is that for each different Stack Exchange site you need to be in a different tab (or window depending on your browser) for each Stack Exchange chat area, and you are able to be in many chat-rooms in those windows (depending on your reputation points).

What I am requesting (suggesting) is for a Stack Exchange chat-room area where you have **all** of the rooms that you are in on the Exchange in one place and are able to get all of the responses and replies in one place without the need to change windows as you do now.

Comment: All the cool kids hang out at the Tavern: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta

Comment: @random, I am not sure what this has to do with this question.

Comment: So you want a mega room that has all the comments thrown together? The sidebar should show you messages coming in from other rooms you're in

Comment: @random, basically, idk abt _mega_ but basically, if one is in a few rooms, there attention is only on one or two at a time

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why so many chats?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69909/why-so-many-chats)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This question is asking for a "list all rooms I'm in, regardless of server" page; the other one is asking for "merge chat.SO, chat.MSO and chat.SE together." @Tim

Comment: @PopularDemand -- thank you, that is **exactly** what i am asking!

Comment: @PopularDemand "get all of the responses and replies in one place" says "I want all of my chats accessible from one tab" to me, which is functionally the same as merging all of the servers.

Answer (score 8):

There are only 3 chat servers:

1. chat.meta - rooms associated with meta.stackoverflow.com
2. chat.so - rooms associated with stackoverflow.com
3. chat.se - rooms associated with SU, SF, and all of the SE2.0 sites.

When you click the chat link at the top of a site, it takes you to a filtered view showing you just the rooms associated with that site, since presumably that's what you are interested in as you came from that site.  However, you can view [all of the rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=all&sort=active) rather than limiting it to a certain site.

So, for me, I have one tab for chat.se and I am in rooms for english.se, crypto.se, security.se, music.se, gaming.se, etc.

So, if I've understood your post correctly, we already have what you're asking for with the exception of Stack Overflow (because it is so much larger) and Meta Stack Overflow (because the unicorns here are special *and demanding*).

Comment: +1 for special and demanding unicorns.

Comment: *demanding* meaning "Need to be kept away from the other kids", no? :)

Comment: @Rebecca Any chance of being able to view/join favourite rooms regardless of the server they're on? Something like a unified chat dashboard?

Comment: I believe when we were asked the consensus was "let's merge with chat.SE" -- and then nothing happened :)

Comment: @AdamLear, that is basically my question.

Comment: Sounds like a userscript is in order!

Comment: @TheUnhandledException - if it was something that could be done with a userscript that'd be perfect.

Comment: I think this answer needs an update.