# Merge chat.SE chat.SO and chat.meta.SO into one network-wide chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Put all SE Chatrooms Together?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98369/put-all-se-chatrooms-together)

Currently there are at least three independent instances of chat running on the SE network:

1. https://chat.stackoverflow.com
2. https://chat.stackexchange.com
3. http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com

On chat.SE I have a list of favourites rooms from the lower traffic sites I'm interested in. It's convenient being able to open one tab and hits "rejoin favourites" to auto-join all of them. However this *doesn't* join my favourite rooms on chat.SO and chat.meta.SO because they're isolated instances of the chat software it seems. Since there are interesting rooms in all three I have to open three tabs. This is tedious and results in less activity in some chatrooms I suspect.

It would be good for users, chat and the site in general if it were possible to participate in all network chatrooms, including the SO and MSO ones from one single tab, in the same way the rest of the SE 2.0 network chats can be accessed from one place.

Comment: There's an argument (which I don't necessarily agree with) about the volume of traffic on the chat.SO instance - but I can't see a reason why chat.meta.SO shouldn't be on chat.SE

Comment: @ChrisF - volume in relation to moderation issues, or server side scalability?

Comment: Either/both. Merging has been brought up before, and "traffic" was given as the reason for not doing it.

Comment: @YannisRizos moderation is the bit I'm less sure on, but I think the problems with moderation will need addressing at some point either way

Comment: @awoodland Well, I think SE 2.0 mods moderating SO chat rooms would be a good thing, SO mods have more than enough work just with the main site. It would certainly be just a byproduct of the merge and wouldn't concern most of users, but it was why I gave you my upvote ;)

Comment: At the moment I like that individual rooms are (broadly) able to set the bar on what is and isn't acceptable conduct, within a relatively wide range - Something like: [Add escalation system to chat flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112756) is a great idea with or without a merge.

Comment: @awoodland There are other good ideas floating around, moderating chat is one of the most unpleasant and unproductive activities... Anyways, while traffic is a bit of an issue as ChrisF already mentioned, I think it's about time we got one chat to rule them all.

Comment: There are almost never flags in chat and every sites moderators can handle flags for any chat, since I almost never see flags I doubt they happen very often.

Comment: @awoodland sorry, you are a duplicate ^_^

Comment: @ama - Damn I searched high and low for something like that but couldn't find it anywhere

Comment: @awoodland hehe I only know because I **asked** the question and yours seemed very _very_ familiar :-P

Comment: I'm all for this as long as SO isn't the only visible chat. Maybe merge meta.SO into SE and leave SO to be SO?