# All my starred chat rooms aren't showing up on the main SE chat website

Tags: bug, chat

So, I started using chat today and starred the Minecraft Talk room on Arqade and the Python room on Stack Overflow. Yet when I go to the [main list](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=favorite) it only shows Minecraft Talk, and I can't even find the Python room without directly using the chat link on Stack Overflow. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow has its own dedicated chat instance*, so the list of favourite rooms aren't shared between it and the main Stack Exchange chat site. The Python room is presumably listed on your [list of favorites on chat.SO](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=favorite).

<sub>*As does Meta Stack Overflow</sub>

Comment: It seems kind of odd for those two sites to have dedicated chat instances, I would think it would be easier having them all on chat.SE.

Comment: See: [Put all Stack Exchange chatrooms together?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98369) (and also: [Why so many chats?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69909))

Comment: Well, based on what I'm seeing it seems like they *are* slowly conglomerating the chats together into the central hub of chat.SE.

Comment: Right, all of the sites have their chats there except for SO (because of its size) and Meta (for various reasons).