# Assimilate chat.MSE into chat.SE

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, chat, meta

Recently, there was a user in the Tavern who was... um, either highly delusional or a bot. In any case, since unfortunately no employees were around at the time, it took us almost a full *hour* to get enough people to spam/offensive/abusive flag one of his messages in order to get a measly 30-minute chat ban.

All of us in Teachers' Lounge felt so helpless in that we could barely do anything in order to... well, be moderators. Even our custom "other" flags went unhandled since no employees were around at the time.

Therefore, I hereby propose that we assimilate chat.MSE into chat.SE!

[image: You will be assimilated. Resistance is Futile.]

[This post is related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69909/180276), but it was from a long time ago, and things have changed.

- chat.meta.SO is no more. The reasoning provided for having a separate meta chat was:

  > And MSO? hmm... well... er... hmmm... MSO is a curious beast; in part it discusses stackoverflow.com and in part it discusses the Stack Exchange Network.

  That no longer applies after the MSO/MSE split.
- chat.SO is active enough to have a separate thing, but chat.MSE is much less so. (This is obviously true given the fact that it took over an hour for a single blue person to appear.)
- The above point is especially exemplary considering that most users with chat moderation privileges on Chat.SE don't have those privileges on Chat.MSE.
- In order to participate in Chat.MSE, users without the association bonus need to have explicit participation on this site. This is unlike Chat.SE, where any user whose combined rep across all sites is 20+ can chat in any chat room on any site (except Stack Overflow).
- Meta isn't even as special as it used to be (yes yes I know, we're very *special* unicorns, but just listen to me), since it's now basically a "normal" site (in the technical sense. The users are... well, we're something *different*.). Since it's actually much less active than other *.SE.coms, I don't see why it's treated so differently.

Comment: We all know the real reason is that you want to be blue in the Tavern! Don't hide it!

Comment: I really like this idea, not because I want to be blue (I personally, rather like the tavern being a more "neutral" ground), but because I'd really like to hang out there, but don't for the same reasons I don't go to SO chat much. They are entirely different chat networks and I soon start spawning more and more chat tabs (on SE chat I can have one tab and see all my rooms in the sidebar). If you could at least integrate chat.mse and chat.se so I could have that it would be awesome! I don't see that happening however... chat is pretty dead development wise it seems :(

Comment: On the other hand, that might make the tavern so flooded it wouldn't be the tavern anymore.. hm.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS We'll just put Doorknob here in charge of the upsizing renovations, then. Hopefully he doesn't get incorporated into the building itself.

Comment: I prefer to have MSE moderators, but if the team refuse then what you suggest makes sense as well. Having trolls roaming free is infuriating! ;)

Comment: Guess they don't have a raft of SE staff rooms we don't see

Answer (score 15):

Meh; I was around for part of this (the start and end) - there was a drunk guy posting random nonsense.

To be blunt: even on chat.SE, where there are tons of moderators, more noise was generated by folks *responding* to this trollish behavior than was caused by the user himself. I edited one crude comment on chat.meta, but otherwise just ignored the guy - if y'all had done likewise (or just flagged one of the comments) then this would've been a non-issue. The solution here isn't technical.

IIRC, chat.meta is occasionally used as a staging area for the chat code, so I'll defer to balpha & Marc on the issue of whether or not merging these systems is even desirable. The larger issue of multiple chat servers and moderators is one that's been debated many times before... It's worth noting that there are relatively few moderators on chat.so as well, which gets *more* traffic than chat.se. If we're gonna invest any time into fixing cross-server issues, that'd be the one to tackle.

Comment: I don't think merging them is a good idea, but I *do* think giving the chat.meta users slightly more control over moderation is a good idea.

Comment: I agree - that's why room owners can now kick/mute misbehaving users.